# JavaScript: How can i set a variable in a string

Tags: javascript

I would like to set attributes on all elements that id starts with "id-" followed by a number [e.g. id="id-0", id="id-1) and so on]. I thought about something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

function Prepare() {
    var = 0
    while(document.getElementById("id-{var}")) {
        document.getElementById("id-{var}").setAttribute("rows", "60");
        var += 1
    }

</script>
```

How can i set a var like this in JavaScript?

Comment: `if (document.getElementById("id-"+variable)){ /** do stuff */};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should accomplish the task:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

function Prepare() {
    var ct = 0
    while(document.getElementById("id-"+ct)) {
        document.getElementById("id-"+ct).setAttribute("rows", "60");
        ct += 1
    }

</script>
```

alternatively:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function Prepare() {
    for(var ct = 0;document.getElementById("id-"+ct);ct++) {
       document.getElementById("id-"+ct).setAttribute("rows", "60");
     }
</script>
```

Comment: ct += 1 is equivalent to ct = ct + 1 or ct++

Comment: @ user: Gosh, ***really***?!?!?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You learn something new everyday. Haha, but yeah. Its quite handy

Comment: @Shawn31313: My comment *might* have been sarcastic. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on compatability you could use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll):

```
function Prepare(){
    var els = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=id]");

    for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++){
        els[i].setAttribute("rows", 60);
    }
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/Adnhz/3/)**